# CSS before not working

Tags: html, css

I just building website everything working well but when I am trying to apply  :before or :after pseudo-elements on some element so the small bubble should be behind the big one and it somehow not working and don't know why.

```css
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 135px;
  height: 135px;
  background-color: #666;
  -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
  -moz-border-radius: 75px;
  -o-border-radius: 75px;
  -ms-border-radius: 75px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(236, 3, 91, 0.20);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(236, 3, 91, 0.20);
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(236, 3, 91, 0.20);
  z-index: 10;
}
.bubble.black:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
  -moz-border-radius: 75px;
  -o-border-radius: 75px;
  -ms-border-radius: 75px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(236, 3, 91, 0.20);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(236, 3, 91, 0.20);
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(236, 3, 91, 0.20);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble black"></div>
```

Comment: its working fine..any specific browser??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove `z-index` from parent and use `z-index: -1` on pseudo element

```css
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 135px;
  height: 135px;
  background-color: #666;
  border-radius: 75px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(236, 3, 91, 0.20);
}
.bubble.black:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 75px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(236, 3, 91, 0.20);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble black"></div>
```